# c# win10 app send console command to turnkey linux minecraft

Tags: c#, minecraft

I'd like to automate some command line instructions in Minecraft for my kids' server.  Is there a way to send a command to the Minecraft instance from win10 c# to a Debian turnkey Minecraft server instance running MineOS?  I searched around but couldn't find anything specific to what I'm looking for.  I would imagine it would have something to do with sending over an open port but it seems like a bit of a black box.

It doesn't need to be a command directly to the MineOS "console", I just need to get the command(s) to the server instance so it's recognized and executed.   It's the java edition of Minecraft in case that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I know there is no API that Minecraft console exposes. So you will need 2 services, one running on your Win10 and sending some requests through API to the second service deployed near the Minecraft server: in this case on the Debian. I guess you'll need a bash script to tell the final command to the Minecraft and executing it from the C# code. To execute bash scripts from C# you'll need to start a new process using `Process` class. One way to achieve communication between the services is using ASP.NET Core

Comment: Hey @Karen - thanks for replying.  So the API parts I can handle and I get how to shell out to execute a local command line since I'm a C# developer by trade.  There's got to be something exposed for the bash command to talk to, though, on the Debian side.  Can you point me in the right direction there?  That's the core of my question.  What does bash talk to?  It would seem like the console in the game is in a different context than the bash console would be.

Comment: Dear @DonSlattery, the question is already Minecraft specific. I can suggest one option but it's not the best one for sure. You can use Linux pipelines/streams to stimulate some user inputs within the Minecraft console. But I recommend you to research all the ways you can achieve success and choose a better option.

Comment: thanks a bunch for the answers.  I do appreciate it!